# Doctrine criteria MEMBER_OF trouble

Tags: laravel-5, doctrine-orm

I use laravel-doctrine and try to use criteria. But when I use memberOf comparison I got an error "Unknown comparison operator: MEMBER_OF"

QueryExpressionVisitor which throws an error doesnt have "MEMBER_OF" case in SWITCH operator (walkComparison() method)

```
Criteria::create()->andWhere(
    Criteria::expr()->memberOf(':user', 'e.likedUsers')
);
```

how can I use memberOf comparison with criteria API?